NightwatchJS - mochawesome reporter doesn't report the messages from individual calls like browser.verify
I am using NightwatchJS 3.6.1 with mochawesome 7.1.3.
In the report it generates, the messages that go along with each test line are not coming along with the line result.
Example:
browser.verify.ok(body.debugMessage, 'debugMessage found.')

output:
[green checkbox] verify.ok


Here is part of the config:
        chrome: {
        launch_url: urlBase,
        desiredCapabilities: {
            browserName: 'chrome'
        },
        screenshots: {
            enabled: true,
            path: SCREENSHOT_PATH + 'chrome'
        },
        "cli_args": [
            "--verbose",
            "--headless"
        ],
        webdriver: {
            start_process: true,
            port: 9515,
            server_path: require('chromedriver').path
        },
        reporter: (browser, done) => {
            // Customize  reporter here
            const reporter = require('mochawesome');
            const reportPath = path.join(__dirname, 'reports', 'chrome-report');
            console.log(reportPath);
            reporter(output, module, () => {
                done();
            }, reportPath);
        }
    },

